# Sanitize an input request param from XSS attack

Tags: xss, owasp, sanitization

I am working on securing the input request params to my application from XSS attacks. I came across the owasp cheat sheet for securing against XSS attack. I am following the instructions on  https://github.com/owasp/java-html-sanitizer.

I have managed to block the XSS attack (done by means of supplying events like onMouseOver appended to input param) by using below code :

```
PolicyFactory policy = Sanitizers.FORMATTING.and(Sanitizers.BLOCKS);
value = policy.sanitize(value); // Value is the "value" of input param
```

This converts something like ***name=FIRST" onmouseover="alert('222')*** supplied in querystring : ***X=Val1&Y=&Z=&A=false&name=FIRST" onmouseover="alert('222')&B=456&C=123***
to

```
<span class="db-wrap-name" title="FIRST&quot;" onload&#61;&#34;alert(&#39;222s2&#39;)="">FIRST" onload="alert('2222')</span>
```

My question is this Sanitization sufficient to protect the input param from XSS?

PS: Can someone point me to a linear source to go through the OWASP HTML Sanitization. I have managed to get understanding on this but there are gaps. It will be great if I can get a linear source.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No. This is not sufficient. See  [OWASP XSS Cheat Sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) .

For Fighting XSS you must:

1. Validate your inputs
2. Eventually escape some characters in the inputs
3. Encode the data you send back to the client.